# Windows Workflow Foundation Repeat an Activity Every X minutes

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

What is the best way to repeat a code activity every 2 minutes until a certain condition is met?

Say I have the following code activity that checks a database to see that a batch of reports has been completed.

```
public sealed class CheckReportsAreComplete : CodeActivity
{        
    public InArgument<int> ReportBatchId{ get; set; }       
    public OutArgument<bool> HaveReportsCompleted{ get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {             
        bool haveCompleted = ReportService.HaveReportsCompleted((context.GetValue(this.ReportBatchId));

        HaveReportsCompleted.Set(context, haveCompleted);                       
    }
}
```

I need this code activity to run every 2 minutes and continue processing when the OutArgument HaveReportsCompleted has been set to true. Should I just use Timer.Sleep in the code or is that bad practice?

I'd assume I'd need a combination of a while/do while with a delay and condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres the solution I came up with:

[image]